# Project build error: Non-parseable POM: Duplicated tag: 'dependencies' (position: START_TAG seen ...</properties>\r\n\r\n\t<dependencies>... @55:16)

Tags: maven

I'm just beginner for java rest api web service. I want to add GSON in my project. So i just added gson jar using add external jar option in java build path and added the dependency in pom.xml file, but it shows the below error,

**Project build error: Non-parseable POM: Duplicated tag: 'dependencies' (position: START_TAG seen ...\r\n\r\n\t... @55:16)**

Could you please suggest me an idea to fix this issue?

And this is pom.xml file,

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example.feeds</groupId>
<artifactId>RESTfullProject</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>RESTfullProject</name>

<build>
    <finalName>RESTfullProject</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
        <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support <dependency> <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId> 
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId> </dependency> -->
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.16</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add all the `<dependency>` tags within a single `<dependencies>` tag. You don't need to include each dependency under separate dependencies tag.

**The right way:**

```
    <dependencies>
       <dependency1>
       </dependency1>

       <dependency2>
       </dependency2>
    </dependencies>
```